# Show wrapped div in one line

Tags: css

I'm trying to build an image slider (no problems with the js!):

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="inside">
      <img src="pic1">
      <img src="pic2">
      <img src="pic3">
      <img src="pic4">
   </div>
</div>
```

with the following style:

```
#wrapper{position:relative; width:300px; overflow:hidden;}
#inside{position:relative;}
#inside img{width:140px;}
```

When the width of the images (pic1,2,3,4) is greater than the width of the #wrapper(i.e. 300px), the rest of the images are moved to another line, i.e, instead of

```
pic1 pic2 pic3 pic4
```

I get

```
pic1 pic2
pic3 pic4
```

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the size of your `#inside` div to the size of your images and just hide all that extra space with `overflow:hidden` in your `#wrapper` div.

So it will be something like this:

```
#wrapper{position:relative; width:300px; overflow:hidden; }
#inside{position:relative; width:500px; }
```

Comment: @user1073201 Check this demo out, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/zFdmB/) if you increase the size of the `#wrapper` div, you should see more images appearing. It works :D

Comment: The trick was adding the line #inside img{width:100px;} (which I added additionally). Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: @user1073201 Depending on how your images are contained, the width of the images all combined (including padding and margin) should equal the width of your `#inside` container.

Comment: This might be the correct answer - as far as the number of images contained is not going to change. Otherwise this is useless. http://jsfiddle.net/zFdmB/1/

Comment: @roXon depending on the need of the user, that can be true, otherwise javascript would have to be used to change the width of the container.

Comment: And that's the correct answer! `var imgN = $('#inside img').length, imgW = 140; $('#inside').width(imgN*imgW);` (If jQuery is used.)

Comment: @roXon `I'm trying to build an image slider (no problems with the js!):` ..you have to focus on the needs of the OP. Maybe its a slider for some content that is for presentation only and will not be touched again. I could have rewritten the whole slider and given it a CMS for the OP but does that answer the question? it might, but was it what the OP was looking for? maybe not.

Comment: @Andres You'll be surprised how many times I suggested something that the OP never thought about and was accepted for pointing that out. Anyway, I completely agree with you. +1'd

Comment: @roXon i know, i understand where you're coming from, i feel the same way, but for me the opposite is also true. Gotten a lot of burns for trying to justify what i think it's right versus what the OP actually needs, so i just stick to answering based on what information is given. Internet fist bump!.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand - what's the point of the 300px wrapper if your images inside are bigger?  Unless you absolutely position them, they're of course going to wrap if they're too wide.

Comment: lets say each image is 150px, and the wrapper is 320px. what I want is the images to be in line, and not in two lines.